# how can I safely convert byte array to string in C# on Linux (under mono)?

Tags: c#, string, encoding, mono, arrays

Currently I am using something like this:

```
private static ASCEncoding = new Encoding();
...
...
```

and my method:

```
...
public object some_method(object BinaryRequest)
{
 byte[] byteRequest = (byte[])BinaryRequest;
 string strRequest = ASCEncoding.GetString(byteRequest);
  ...
}
```

some characters when checked under Windows are different when checked Under Linux

```
9I9T (win)
98T  (linux)
```

Comment: It's because you're using ASCII encoding. CPs are different.

Comment: You need to use the _correct_ encoding on both ends.  And you need to make sure it can encode every character you need.  Use UTF8.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile; `Encoding` is abstract.

Comment: @SLaks, I haven't include all the code. This is just the important info I thought will supplement the question :)

Comment: As SLaks says, use UTF8 if you can. If you're dealing with legacy data you might need to use `Encoding.Default` to use the ANSI code page for the current locale, but of course that text won't be portable to locales that use different code pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are communicating between systems, it's a good idea to use a specific and documented encoding for your text. For text written in the English language (including programming languages which use English for keywords/etc), the UTF-8 encoding is likely to use the fewest overall number of bytes in the encoded representation.

```
byte[] byteRequest = (byte[])BinaryRequest;
string strRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteRequest);
```

Obviously to use this, you are expected to produce your requests using the same encoding.

```
string strRequest = ...
byte[] byteRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string stringValue = Encoding.Default.GetString(byteArray);
```

Comment: Whether or not this works depends totally on the data in `byteArray` and the locale of the system.

Comment: Be careful with System.Text.Encoding.Default as it could be different on each machine it is run. That's why it's recommended to always specify an encoding, such as UTF-8.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, what he said.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that `Encoding.Default` differs depending on the locale. See the caution in the Remarks section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx